# Python - Turn two lists into a pairwise table

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have carried out pairwise comparisons amongst *Pi* to *Pj* populations. I have two lists: *list_x* and *list_y*, each contains values for these pairwise comparisons for different factors.

E.g.

```
        list_x    list_y
P1:P2   A         a 
P1:P3   B         b
P2:P3   C         c
```

I want to use Python to combine these two lists into a single array. Something like this:

```
    P1  P2  P3 
P1  .   a   b
P2  A   .   c
P3  B   C   .
```

I have tried looking for a function that does this (in NumPy and SciPy) but can't find one. Short of writing my own function to do this, I was wondering if anyone knew of a way that already exists to achieve this?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/30058133/901925, which fills in triangular arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I dont there is way to do this.

At first, the data you provided is not a possible list or numpy.array object in python, which will lack of the P1:P2 column information.

So I would like to suggest do this by write code by your self.

Comment: The `np.triu` family of functions can be used to map a 1d array onto the upper or lower 2d triangular arrays.  That's been discussed in some recent SO questions.  Try a search.

Answer (score 0):

you can use indexs=list(itertools.combinations(range(3),2)) to return the list of lower triangular index, and assigning the values from the list to the matrix.